# Creating a Evenly Rounded Mesh Surface

Tags: mesh

I was wondering if anyone could help me with evenly rounding parts of my mesh's surface.

What I mean by that is shown in the picture below, with the trouble area circled in red.  Basically I'd like to make the circled area of the mesh to resemble the illustration on the right, with a rounded, even surface as opposed to the flattish, uneven surface of the left.

[image]

I'm also having a similar issue with the head of my mesh shown below:

[image]

If you look at the area of the mesh highlighted by the red line in the picture on the left, you can see based off the way the light is bouncing off the mesh's surface that there is what looks like an edge when the head is supposed to be completely rounded.  This problem is further highlighted by the pictures on the right which show the mesh's head shown from another angle, revealing that the head has a rounded, almost box shape.  This is not what I wanted, as I wanted the head to a have more evenly rounded egg-like shape rather the current vaguely box-like shape.

I've tried using Proportional Editing, but I've found that Proportional Editing tends to create uneven surfaces so I'm not quite sure how to go about this.

Any help with this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try selecting some of the vertices and use "Smooth Vertex" in the Tool Bar. You may have to try different selections...

Comment: Just a note: I think one of the things that's going to make it difficult to edit this mesh is that it looks like you've applied a subsurf or done some smoothing so you're having to deal with a lot of vertices. Ideally you want to work with as few vertices as necessary to create the desired shape.

Comment: Since the model is extremely simplistic I can easily use the Decimate modifier to reduce the amount of geometry without worrying about losing any detail, however since I'm also using the Mirror modifier it creates a problem where the model no longer has an even amount of vertexes on both sides.  This in turn results in the faces caught in the middle being cut in half, creating an unwanted seam and a bunch of problematic faces to work with near the middle.

Comment: So if I were to apply the Mirror modifier, I would be able to reduce the amount of geometry, but I would lose the ability to be able to keep the model symmetrical as I modified it.  Also, while experimenting with the Decimate modifier I've noticed that the modifier also ends up creating a number of triangular faces in various areas on my mesh that I'm worried are going to cause further problems.

Comment: Looking through my project folder, I do have an older version of the lower poly version of the model that has around 900 tris instead of the current version that has about double the amount.  Would that be more workable than the current one I'm working on?